# How to wildcard include JAR files when compiling?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, package

I have the following in a java file (MyRtmpClient.java):

```
import org.apache.mina.common.ByteBuffer;
```

and `ByteBuffer` is inside a JAR file (with the proper directory structure of course).
That jar file and others I need are in the same directory as the .java file.

Then I compile with the line:

```
javac -cp ".;*.jar" MyRtmpClient.java
```

But I get the error:

> `MyRtmpClient.java:3: package org.apache.mina.common does not exist
>
>   import org.apache.mina.common.ByteBuffer;`

How can I include jar files in my project?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

your command line is correct, but there are some considerations:

- you must have javac >= 1.6, because only in that version the compiler parses the "*" as various JAR files.
- you must be running Windows, because ";" is the path separator for that operating system only (it doesn't work on Unix, the path separator on Unix is ":").

I'm assuming that the JAR file has the proper directory structure as you stated.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that it would parse the *. I guess it's been a while since I compiled anything needing a classpath from the command line.

Comment: Yours is probably the answer to my dilemma. I have JDK 1.5  :(

Comment: this is the source: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options

Answer (score 16):

javac does not understand *.jar in the classpath argument. You need to explicitly specify each jar. e.g.

```
javac -cp ".;mina.jar" MyRtmpClient.java
```

Comment: Yes, * is usually interpreted by the shell, but here it doesn't get a chance.

Comment: I tried using *.jar on Linux before writing my answer and it didn't work.

Comment: Depends on JDK version; see above.

Comment: So it seems to understand -cp *.jar if I remove the quotes but it does not understand -cp .:*.jar

Comment: the class path foo/* is expanded into foo/a.jar;foo/b.jar;foo/c.jar

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.12 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and to compile a number of packages (and in my case I don't need to do anything with .java files in them) with a single .java file in the same directory, this is what I've used: `javac -cp ".:dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5.jar:dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5-javadoc.jar:dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.5-sources.jar:jackson-core-2.2.3.jar:javax.mail.jar" Main.java`.

Comment: What does the "." in ".;mina.jar" do?

Comment: I've found it does not support *.jar but it will support *. This is with both of them in quotes so that the command line doesn't alter them,

Answer (score 11):

In javac JDK 6 and above You could use (**note lack of .jar**):

```
javac -cp ".;*" MyRtmpClient.java
```

to quote [javac - Java programming language compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options)

> As a special convenience, a class path element containing a basename of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR.
>
> For example, if directory foo contains a.jar and b.JAR, then the class path element foo/* is expanded to A.jar;b.JAR, except that the order of jar files is unspecified. All jar files in the specified directory, even hidden ones, are included in the list. A classpath entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current directory.

Answer (score 9):

If you have utilities `find` and `tr` at your disposal (e.g. you're working Linux), you could do:

```
javac -cp .:`find * -name "*.jar" | tr "\n" ":"` MyRtmpClient.java
```

All *jar* files in the current directory and all it's sub-directories will be added (shell command lists all *jar* files and puts colons as separators between them).

---

Explanation:

- pair of the backticks ( **`** ) denote shell commands to be executed,
- `find * -name "*.jar"` finds and lists all *jar* files in hierarchy whose root is current folder,
- vertical bar ( **|** ) is pipe; connects output of `find` to the input of next command,
- `tr "\n" ":"` replaces all *newline* characters with *colon* characters.

Answer (score 8):

In your case, I think JAVAC can not found jars file.

Please try:

PROJECT_PATH
- lib\a.jar
- src\package\b.java

```
cd @PROJECT_PATH

javac -classpath lib\a.jar src\package\b.java
```

Comment: In this case use " javac -cp .;.\lib\\** src\package\b ".  That rule will match jars under lib and also wildcard classes in the current directory.

Answer (score 4):

Probably below syntax will work on windows dos command

```
javac -cp ".;first.jar;second.jar;third.jar" MyRtmpClient.java
```

Comment: You don't need the quotes unless there are spaces in the classpath and in this case, there aren't.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, the option ".;*" etc. which are mentioned above did not seem to work. I tried and found that :
`javac -cp '<location of jars>/*' MyRtmpClient.java`

works:

`<location of jar>` can be /usr/local/classes/* or /home/developer/MyProject/*

Answer (score -2):

try including the jar file in your command line so :

javac MyRtmpClient.java ByteBuffer.jar

Comment: No, definitely not. "Usage: javac <options> <source files>"

Comment: I'll try. But there are many of them. I dont like the idea of being forced to include all jar files one by one.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use `-cp` with *Javac*. You have to use `-classpath` instead (assuming the other settings are correct).