# How to add .jar file to the Java Code

Tags: java, guava

I have a java code where I want to use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries CharMatcher function. I downloaded it, but can't able to add it to my existing code. Can anybody help me how to add that .jar file to the java code (step-by-step). I am using JDK 1.6. Thanks in advance.

I am using the following command:

[image]

And Used follwing code:

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

 String key = "hello";
 Multimap<String, Integer> myMap = HashMultimap.create();
 myMap.put(key, 1);
 myMap.put(key, 5000);
 System.out.println(myMap.get(key));

}

 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
  } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
  }


}
}
```

I store Guava Library and Test.java in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin . Can anybody help me where is the problem because it is showing errors.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064481/newbie-question-how-to-include-jar-files-when-compiling

Comment: Step-by-step instructions would obviously depend on what programming environment you're using: NetBeans, Eclipse, Notepad, BlueJay... what?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Sorry, I am not using NetBeans, Eclipse etc. I am using Javac (JDk 1.6) to run it.

Comment: Well, then see the comment about this being a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064481, because it is!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I used that command but showing above described errors.

Comment: OK, now that we see that: this actually has nothing to do with the classpath or including the jar. The classes you're using are in the package `com.google.common.collect`. You have to do, for example, `import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;` at the top of your Java file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you are using Eclipse as IDE, here is the picture:
[image]

**EDIT**: if you don't use any IDE, you just must use CLASSPATH variable:

```
javac -classpath path_to_your_jar/yourjar.jar your_code.java
```

'-classpath' or '-cp' switch gives you possibility to tell javac where your libraries are located.
See [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for further reference.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using NetBeans, Eclipse etc. I am using Javac (JDk 1.6) to run it.

Comment: Thanks. I used that command but showing above described errors.

Comment: @alessandro: Have you imported needed class (HashMultimap) in your .java file? If not, you want to write 'import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;' in the file begining.

Comment: Sorry, I become crazy. :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your just doing command line, you can either modify the classpath environment variable, or pass the `-classpath` argument on the command line:

Windows: `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;\guava\install\dir\guava.jar`
*nix `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/guava/install/dir/guava.jar`

OR

```
javac -classpath guava\install\dir\guava.jar ...
java -classpath guava\install\dir\guava.jar ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it to your classpath:

- Copy .jar in your project-folder
- Refresh your project-explorer in eclipse (i hope you're using eclipse)
- rightclick .jar
- Buildpath -> add to build path

I hope this helps you, i'm not really sure if this is what you are asking for ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am not using NetBeans, Eclipse etc. I am using Javac (JDk 1.6) to run it.