# Passing parameter from Java Applet to Javascript

Tags: java, classpath

I'm using JSObject to pass value from my Applet to a Javascript function, but when I compile the java applet, occurs an error

```
error: package netscape.javacript does not exist
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;
```

This occurs because in my classpath I didn't pass the path of his .jar file

How can I pass 2 jar file in my classpath ? I need the grfingerjava.jar and another one. How can I do that ?

```
javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4 -nowarn -classpath "C:\Program Files\Griaule\Fingerprint SDK 2009\bin\grfingerjava.jar" src\com\griaule\fingerprintsdk\appletsample\*.java -d "%INSTALLDIR%"
```

Comment: Delimit paths with a semi-colon, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064481/newbie-question-how-to-include-jar-files-when-compiling

Comment: I try put a ';' separator and put the another .jar file, but didn't work. Same error

Comment: @Lucas_Santos I think we are trying to accomplish the same thing. Using JavaApplet to identify from a fingerprint reader and pass it to a JS variable so it is passed to a backend (Say php, ruby, python), did you solve your issue?