# Compiling java with classpath doesn't find all jar files

Tags: java, javac, jakarta-mail

I have a lib folder with many .jar files and one of the files I have is mail.jar (for javax.mail)

When I compile my source code, I use

```
javac -cp .:../lib/ server/MyFile.java
```

And then I get a bunch of errors

```
server/MyFile.java:22: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
                          ^
server/MyFile.java:23: error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
                          ^
server/MyFile.java:24: error: package javax.mail does not exist
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
                 ^
etc
etc
```

However javax.mail should be inside (via mail.jar). I also have activation.jar inside of the lib folder. Note that this mail.jar file I just downloaded today from sun website. It is recent.

What could be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I have added all the jar files manually on the classpath, and it compiles fine. However now when I run MyFile.java, using this command

```
java server.MyFile
```

I get this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:492)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:484)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I can bet u that only prob is jar were not in classpath ,on run alone we can use it , java -cp :/path/to/JARS/ , also we no need the jars on compilation mate @CodeGuy

Comment: the jar is indeed on the classpath...

Comment: okies fine .. can u add more info on stack trace of your update please.

Comment: please see update. full stack trace included.

Comment: please see my first comment mate @CodeGuy  java -cp :/path/to/JARS/  MyFile should work for you

Comment: sorry...i simply didn't understand your english

Comment: okies.. will keep improving :( @CodeGuy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there an easier way to do this?

Since version 6, you can use [*class path wildcards*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html).

```
    javac -cp .:../lib/* server/MyFile.java
```

See also this related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064481/230513).

Comment: @JimN: Feel free to update your answer with the new information.

Comment: See update above. It compiles fine now. This worked great. However now I have the error at run time (see above).

Answer (score -1):

You can set `CLASSPATH=/path/to/java/jar;/path/to/other/jar` (note semicolon) for Unix.

Also look at http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/02/windows-8-set-path-and-classpath-java-windows-7.html