# Add files to classpath or loops in batch files?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have this script in BASH (linux) shells script that adds all *.jar files into the classpath automatically. Is there a way to do the in window's batch file or do I have to add all the files manually?

```
CLASSPATH=.
for file in ./libs/*.jar; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [BAT file to create Java CLASSPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524081/bat-file-to-create-java-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `forfiles` command to loop over the file names.

```
forfiles /M .\libs\*.jar /C "cmd /c set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;@file"
```

Comment: Doesn't work since cmd cannot find forfiles command. I'm using Windows2K and XP.

Comment: Yep, looks like its there. Obviously /M flag didn't work on for command.