# I am trying this script which converts excel to sql have added necessary jars but something is missing Syntax or Java setting IN LINUX

Tags: java, shell

Please give me a simple example with shell script explanation.

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo off

echo -n Enter acl File Location
read acl

echo -n Enter sql File Location
read sql

cd bin
java -classpath .;../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar;../lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar;../lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar;../lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar;../lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar;
../lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar  com/paywithisis/gateway/utility/XLSXToSQLConverter $acl $sql
cd ..
echo $acl
echo $sql
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What have you tried? What error or problem have you encountered? You want me to take time to help you, then please take the time to ask a proper question. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [BAT file to create Java CLASSPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524081/bat-file-to-create-java-classpath)

Comment: Wildcard classpaths only work with jdk6+. In either case, when specifying the class to run you need to use dots, not slashes.

Comment: Separate them by ";" in the classpath.  Eg, `-cp .;../lib/Jar1.jar;../lib/Jar2.jar;../lib2/Jar3.jar`.

Comment: I want this script to be converted in SHELL SCRIPT thats all..

Answer (score 0):

Linux uses **:** to sepearate the parts of the classpath windows uses **;**