# Steps to copy all jar files under lib and run .r file in windows

Tags: java, rjava

I have a maven project and all the jar files are copied to maenLib folder.
I am running the application from commandline using a .r file.
I know how to run this in ubuthu but I wonder how can I make it work under Windows.

I use [BAT file to create Java CLASSPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524081/bat-file-to-create-java-classpath) to set 
ClassPath (not sure this is the right way !!!). But don't know how to run .r file from windows .

Made search in the entire forum but no post gives the entire solution . :(
My requirement is to copy the entire jar files to classpath using .bat file 
and then somehow run my es.r file

Please help me to solve this .
Appreciate any help !!!!